# Top self-intersection of divisors in higher dimensional varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I am trying to understand how to compute, explicitly, the top self intersection of a divisor inside a variety which is not a surface. I am excluding the surface case because there I can use the intersection product among curves and divisors.

Let's consider a specific example: let $X$ be the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^3$ along a line $l$. Suppose I want to compute $(-K_X)^3$, where $-K_X$ is the canonical divisor. I know that $-K_X=4H-E$, where $H$ is the pullback of the hyperplane class in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $E$ is the exceptional divisor associated to the blow-up. I guess I can expand it as

$$(-K_X)^3=(4H-E)^3=64H^3-E^3-48H^2E+12HE^2,$$

but then I'm lost, because I don't know the value of any of these pieces. Arguing as in the surface case, I guess that $H^3=1$, $E^3=-1$, but $H^2E,EH^2$ don't even seem to be well-defined (and I'm just guessing, there is no rigorous thinking behind it).

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm feeling really lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the projection formula. For instance, if $p$ is the projection to $\mathbb{P}^3$, one has
$$
(p^*H)^3 = p^*(H^3) \cdot [X] = H^3 \cdot p_*[X] = H^3 \cdot [\mathbb{P}^3] = 1.
$$
Similarly, if $i : E \to X$ is the embedding, then
$$
H^2 \cdot E = H^2 \cdot i_*[E] = i^*(H^2) \cdot [E] = (i^*H)^2 = 0
$$
since $i^*H = 0$, and analogously
$$
H \cdot E^2 = H \cdot E \cdot i_*[E] = i^*(H \cdot E) \cdot [E] = (i^*H) \cdot (i^*E) = 0.
$$
Finally,
$$
E^3 = E^2 \cdot i_*[E] = i^*(E^2) \cdot [E] = (i^*E)^2 = (-h)^2 = 1,
$$
since $i^*E = -h$, where $h$ is the hyperplane class of $E \cong \mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Dear @Sasha, thanks a lot for the fast reply. Before accepting it though, I have several questions: what is $[X]$ for instance (I guess the class of $X$ in the $0$-degree part of the chow group), why $H^3\cdot [\mathbb{P}^3]=1$, and why in general such computations are correct. Can you provide a reference so that I can understand this answer?

Comment: $[X]$ is the unit in $H^0(X,\mathbb{Z})$, hence taking product with it doesn't change anything. The rest follows from the projection formula $$\alpha \cdot f^*(\beta) = f_*(\alpha) \cdot \beta.$$

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but still these computations don't look correct. The blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^3$ along a line is a Fano 3-fold belonging to the family $2.33$, and therefore $(-K_X)^3=54$. But following your argument we should obtain $65$.

Comment: Yes, my formulas were for the blowup of a point. With the blowup of a line the story is similar, but slightly more complicated. In this case $H^2E = 0$ by the same reason, while $HE^2 = -1$. The most complicated product is $E^3$ --- it reduces to the computation of the normal bundle, but it is easier to compute it from the equality $(H-E)^3 = 0$, which follows from the fact that the linear system $|H-E|$ gives a morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$.